# Is there any way to select a collection contains any of another collection elements?

Tags: jpa, collections, jpql

My `Profile` class has a collection attribute.

```
class Profile {
    private List<String> aliases;
}
```

How can I query for selecting `Profile`s whose `aliases` contains any of given collection?

Say, selecting profiles whose aliases contains any of [`a`, `b`, `c`]?

Comment: No way other than using "OR" together with each value "IN"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
where 'a' member of p.aliases or 'b' member of p.aliases or 'c' member of p.aliases
```

or

```
join p.aliases a where a in ('a','b','c')
```